# Node.js / Socket.io port sharing with IIS & itself

Tags: node.js, iis, socket.io, windows-server

Can Socket.io (running on a node.exe) be made to

- share port 80 and (potentially 443) with an IIS instance
- use all cores of the machine with one port?

And of course, do both at the same time: An IIS instance, and multiple node threads/processes all serving on the same port.

Windows offers inter-process port sharing for a while now, so in theory it should be possible. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158.aspx for details:

> But because WCF and IIS 6.0 both use the kernel-mode HTTP stack (HTTP.sys), IIS 6.0 can share port 80 with other self-hosted WCF services running on the same machine, unlike IIS 5.1.

I guess for the IIS part of my question, the question would be: Does node.exe use **http.sys**?

Comment: Don't think that's possible without using a proxy of some sort (haproxy on unix comes to mind). I may be wrong tho.

Comment: I don't use Node on Windows, but have done my share of Windows dev. Its very unlikely. The port will usually be bound to a process - and I am not familiar with the new interprocess port sharing. IIS *might* have a way to pass through to a node process, via node running on another port. MS has shown some love for Node on Windows recently so I would check MSDN

Comment: Only one program at a time may use a single port. Systems that seem to allow port-sharing actually uses proxies, i.e. one program binds to the port, then the proxy program sends messages to that port to other programs.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I added the reference to http.sys to my question, as this seems to be a little-known fact.

Comment: @EdH IIS does not do WebSockets until version 8 (which is not out yet and needs Windows 8 to run on), so I don't want to use the IISnode for now.

Comment: @LiorCohen Proxying would be acceptable. If haproxy can be used to redirect to IIS or Node.js based on some criteria (uri, http header?), please upgrade your comment to an answer.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy: are you limited to one server or operating system or can you run HAProxy on a Linux box in-front of your IIS/Node servers?

Comment: @LiorCohen Not limited to one machine, but limited to Windows